# How to download only amex and nyse data from CRSP?

Tags: equities, market-data, market

I am a beginner and I have a very elementary question, but I don't know where to find the answer!

I am downloading the `CRSP` monthly stock files for 20 years. I want to have only `AMEX` and `NYSE` stocks. But I think `CRSP` has all stocks including `NASDAQ`. How can I *keep only NYSE and AMEX* and delete any other markets from the data? Is there any indicator which shows which stock is traded in which market?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the `CRSP` database, for each stock there is a field called `EXCHCD`. This field will indicate you the exchange. Here are the exchange codes:

[image]

So if you keep only the stocks with codes 1 and 2 you should be good to go.